# How to adjust shadow dynamically with height of view in ios?

Tags: ios, dynamic, uiview, shadow, rounded-corners

I added the shadow to the view with rounded `corners` and it works. But when `frame` of view changes `shadow` won't change its size according to view.
I have tried the following:

```
-(void)addShadow:(UIView *)view withCornerRad : (int)radius{
    view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    CALayer *ViewLayer = view.layer;
    [ViewLayer setMasksToBounds:NO ];
    ViewLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    ViewLayer.shadowOpacity = 1.0 ;
    ViewLayer.shadowRadius = 2.0 ;
    ViewLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake( 0 , 0 );
    ViewLayer.cornerRadius = radius;
    ViewLayer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds].CGPath;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have to update shadow of view each time you change view frame

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Apples view programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> Views are responsible for drawing content, handling multitouch events, and managing the layout of any subviews.

So you can change your shadow in two ways:
1. By subclassing UIView with overriding layoutSubviews function, where you can set new shadow size.
2. You can override your controllers viewDidLayoutSubviews() method, where you can set new shadow size.

Best regards!

Comment: In this solution the shadow will be redrawn each time. I also fond the solution by adding observer you can redraw the shadow. self.container.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.init(rawValue: 0) , context: nil)

Comment: Is't there any solution that automatically handle the shadow size?

Comment: -(void) viewDidLayoutSubview {  
        [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];  
        [self addShadow:self.youView withCornerRad:5.0];  
}

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)addShadow:(UIView *)view withCornerRad : (int)radius
{
    view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    CALayer *ViewLayer = view.layer;
    ViewLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    ViewLayer.shadowRadius  = 10;
    ViewLayer.shadowOffset  = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    ViewLayer.shadowOpacity = 2;
    ViewLayer.masksToBounds = NO;

    UIEdgeInsets shadowInsets     = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    UIBezierPath *shadowPath      = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(view.bounds, shadowInsets)];
    ViewLayer.shadowPath    = shadowPath.CGPath;


}
```

try this if you want shaddow top,left ,bottom, right side of view